# Another way to write this line down? JPA stuff

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The line is:

```
recipeRepository.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(recipeSet::add);
```

`recipeRepository` is my Spring data layer. It finds all the recipes in the DB and adds them to the set. I'm not really familiar with lambdas and `::` operators, so I'm wondering if there's another way to write argument `recipeSet::add` down?

Comment: Since that is not the JPA API, then perhaps update your title

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? This is almost impossible to read. I *think* that what you want is just something like `recipeSet.addAll(recipes.findAll())` (but even this should almost certainly be replaced by a more specific query method--make sure you've read the docs on how to create them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `findAll()` method returns an iterator. You can solve the problem by overriding it in your `recipeRepository` as follows

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Recipe r")
Set<Recipe> findAll();
```

that way it will return a set then you can do something like:

```
Set<Recipe> recipeSet = recipeRepository.findAll();
```

without doing any conversion or iteration

Comment: It's hard to tell from the original post, but it seems like they're already in a `Set<Recipe>`. Starting from that and adding your answer, It should be possible to use simply change `recipeRepository.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(recipeSet::add);` to `recipeRepository.findAll();`, since `iterator()` and `forEachRemaining(recipeSet::add)` effectively negate each other.

Comment: `findAll()` natively returns `Iterable<T>` which can't be cast to `Set<T>` without some type of conversion like the OP was doing. You can fix that by implementing your own `findAll()` in the repository. I ran into the same issue as well

Comment: Yes; I inferred that OP was already doing that, since it was said "finds all the recipes in the DB and adds them to the set".

Comment: Right but I believe it was him explaing what this was doing `recipeRepository.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(recipeSet::add);`